# test class with @auraenabled methods in apex class

Tags: apex, lightning, httpcalloutmock

How to increase coverage of apex class that includes @auraenabled method in apex class?

Comment: You just call them like normal in your unit test. They're the same as any normal static method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you'd test any other code, by executing the method under test. For example:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String TestController(String username, String password) {
    try {
        String name = username;
        String pass = password;
        if(name == 'test@test.test' && pass == 'pass')
            return 'true';
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

And your Test class:

```
@isTest
private class lightningForgotPasswordControllerTest
{
    @isTest
    static void TestForgotPassword()
    {
        String result = LightningForgotPasswordController.TestController('test@test.test', 'pass');
        System.assertEquals(null, result);
    }
}
```